# SCM Manager broken after updating: HTTP error 503 Service unavailable

Tags: git, scmmanager

I have problem in scm manager,
when I try to enter localhost:8080 I get the following error:

**HTTP ERROR: 503
Problem accessing /scm/. Reason:
service unavailable
powered by jetty://**

I am new to scm server, I do not understand the error.

Comment: Updating what to what?

Comment: updating System Windows

Comment: **Write better questions!**. What Windows version? What updates - patch Tuesday was already 3 weeks ago. And [edit] your question, don't just answer in the comments. All essential info should be in the question, comments may disappear.

Comment: Before updating the system I normally accesses the server against scm manager after having installed the updates I get the HTTP error 503

Comment: the version of windows is windows server 2012

Comment: please could you have any idea for this?

Comment: Please have a look at the output of the scm-managers logfile. Are there any stacktraces?

Comment: how to attach a file here ?

Comment: that's the first time I ask a question here so I do not see how to attach a file for see the log of scm manager

Comment: Edit your question (the 'edit' link at the bottom of the question) and paste the log in, then select all the log lines and click the `{}` icon in the editor to format them in a code block.

Comment: Edit your question (the 'edit' link at the bottom of the question) and paste the log in, then select all the log lines and click the {} icon in the editor to format them in a code block.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar error, and found the problem to be in corrupt configuration files. Specifically, file `wwwroot/scm/.scm/config/repositories.xml` had been emptied (for whatever reason). An empty configuration file prevented the start of the application. Both removing the file and restoring a backup solved my problem.